# How do I convert this numeric variables into categories

Tags: r, dataframe, integer, categorical-data

I have a column in my dataframe that is year of publication. The entries are numerous such as below:

```
df$year <- c(1989, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2013, 2010, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2016, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995)
```

How do I categorise the data to be per decade, i.e.: **1960-1969 to be 1, 1970-1979 to be 2, etc up to 2010-2020**

Thank you all.

Comment: Do you want the labels to be "1960-1969", or "1"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @akrun I meant tagging me to say I should be dupe-flagging other posts unrelated to this one

Comment: What language/script is this?

Comment: This language is r

Answer (score 2):

One option is `cut`

```
cut(v1, breaks = seq(1960, 2020, by = 10), 
  labels = paste(seq(1960, 2010, by = 10), seq(1969, 2019, by = 10), sep="-"))
```